# Unity scene and game tab are stretched and colliders are are not in sync with the visual mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is a cube:
[a cube with the dimensions (1,1,1) however to the eye the cube looks more of a cuboid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exumY.png)

What is even more annoying is that the box collider is not lining up with the mesh.[an image of the same cube rotated a bit but the box collider not lining up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTZfx.png)

How do I fix this guys?
The same stretching happens equally in the game and scene tabs.

Comment: This might be caused by the scale of a parent GameObject (easter egg 3 or part 4)

Comment: @Savaria is correct, you would need to de-parent the object completely and then change its `transform`. You can re-parent it once you are done.

Comment: Thank you @Savaria .  It did solve my problem! Thx. IDK how this flew over my head

Comment: @Db321 You're welcome :D